# How to organize SpecFlow tests and features in Test Explorer tree

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow, test-explorer

I am using SpecFlow with C#, Visual Studio 2019.

I have a test project with some 1.000+ tests. These tests are grouped in some 100 feature files.

In the Test Explorer tree, all features are grouped under a single node, like:

```
My.Test.Project
+ My.Test.Project
  + My.Test.Project.Feature1
  + My.Test.Project.Feature2
  + My.Test.Project.Feature3
  + My.Test.Project.Feature4
  ...
  + My.Test.Project.Feature99
  + My.Test.Project.Feature100
```

This was fine at first when there were 10-20 feature files, but as the project grows, it becomes more and more difficult to manage. I need to scroll a lot to get to the feature file I want.

I do not want to split this into multiple projects/assemblies just to get these better organized.

I need a way to group features. I need something like:

```
My.Test.Project
+ My.Test.Project
  + My.Test.Project.Group1
    + My.Test.Project.Feature1
        My.Test.Project.Feature1.Scenario1
        My.Test.Project.Feature1.Scenario2
        My.Test.Project.Feature1.Scenario3
        My.Test.Project.Feature1.Scenario4
        My.Test.Project.Feature1.Scenario5
    + My.Test.Project.Feature2
    + My.Test.Project.Feature3
  + My.Test.Project.Group2
    + My.Test.Project.Feature4
    + My.Test.Project.Feature5
    + My.Test.Project.Feature6
  + My.Test.Project.Group3
    + My.Test.Project.Feature7
  ...
  + My.Test.Project.Group10
    + My.Test.Project.Feature99
    + My.Test.Project.Feature100
```

I need features (not scenarios) grouped as above. Upon expanding each feature, it should display the scenarios it contains.

I have tried all the display and grouping options offered by Test Explorer (Namespace, Class etc.). I have tried adding custom namespaces to each feature using `Custom Tool` and `Custom Tool Namespace`. I have tried adding `tags` and grouping features by tags. I have searched a lot and tried a lot of other things I found online, but was unable to get this to work.

Am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: You aren't the only one with this frustration. Check out [Arrange tests in Test Explorer like folder hierarchy when grouping by project, namespace, class](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/arrange-tests-in-test-explorer-like-folder-hierarc/1455849) and [Test Explorer group by should put namespace and class as a tree branch](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/test-explorer-group-by-should-put-namespace-and-cl/764202) for feature requests in the Visual Studio developer community.